# How to open Waze's voice recognition from a 3rd party application?

Tags: android, waze

There is an Android phone with 5.1.1 (Lollipop) version of Android.

In this system after installing Waze, it is still using its own VR (voice recognition) mechanism, (and not the Google Assistant one).

I'm perfectly fine with this, but now looking for a way for a 3rd party application to trigger the "Search by voice" function. Is this somehow achievable?

This one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly using the [Android SpeechRecognizer API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer) rather than its own third-party solution. But, no, there's no way for other apps to trigger this voice search option. Not without some rooted phone madness that automatically opens the app and simulates the button presses or something.

Comment: Could you share some docs for the "rooted phone madness" which simulates the button press? That would be a good solution for me, as the phone is rooted. Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to start navigation in Waze through voice? Because that can be done from a third-party application without relying on weird hacks.

Comment: I don't have the specific destination by text, I want Waze to recognize it by my voice. For me it is also fine if I can start Waze and it will immediately listen for voice input. (But I did not find anything for this either).

Comment: @Daniel But you can use Android's buitl-in SpeechRecognizer API to have the user speak and then send an Intent to Waze telling it which address was spoken. My app can do this with Waze: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_GavinGT.TipTracker_9_1_426am_ready_for_market&hl=en_US

Comment: Yes, I know, but SpeechRecognizer might have no idea of my previous searches and favourites etc, which Waze does. So I think Waze can recognize better my search if it handles the voice input - correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also Android's builtin speech recognizer is not available on my language, whereas Waze can voice search with my language.